# Changing the URL within .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'll try and explain this the best I can; I have two domain names: `www.original.com` and `www.mysite.com/`. Within the site for `www.original.com` there is no content and all the content is hosted in `www.mysite.com/original/`. Now, when I visit `www.original.com` I have set up a redirect like this:

```
redirectMatch 307 ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/original
```

However, I have realised that this is not what I need, because I would like the visitors of the `www.original.com` site to see `www.original.com` on the address bar, and not `http://www.mysite.com/original`. Is there any way to do this in .htaccess? I used to do it in the cPanel of my old hosting account via an addon domain, but the hosting I have now (united-domains.de) do not provide addon domains, apparently.

Thanks

Comment: Do the 2 domains share the same document root?

Comment: No they're completely separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 2 sites are separate, you'll need to rely on mod_proxy. There are a number of ways to create a reverse proxy from the `www.original.com` domain to the `www.mysite.com` domain. The easiest would be to use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.mysite.com/original
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mysite.com/original
```

But these are only applicable inside the server or vhost config. If you don't have access to that, you'll have to use mod_rewrite's `[P]` flag, which hands the target substitution of a `RewriteRule` to mod_proxy, and you can use this within an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?original\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/original/$1 [L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell www.original.com to act like a proxy server. but this may require you more than just editing an htaccess.

See this for more informations : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html